# SQL - Creating a plan record for every employee for every date

Tags: sql, sql-server

There should be a new record each day for an LO, corresponding to their last plan:

```
CREATE TABLE [Table1] ([LO] nvarchar(255), [StartDate] date, [FinalBP] int)

INSERT INTO [Table1] VALUES('Skip', '5/1/2020', 100)
INSERT INTO [Table1] VALUES('Skip', '5/4/2020', 130)
INSERT INTO [Table1] VALUES('Todd', '5/2/2020', 200)
INSERT INTO [Table1] VALUES('Todd', '5/7/2020', 300)
```

**Attempted Code:**

```
SELECT [LO], [startdate],[finalbp], b.[CalendarDate]
      FROM [Table1] a
      CROSS JOIN [CalendarTable] b
      WHERE [StartDate] <= [CalendarDate] AND [CalendarDate] >= '5/1/2020' AND [CalendarDate] <= GETDATE()
```

**Desired Output:**

```
LO    |  Date      |  FinalBP

Skip  |  5/1/2020  |  100
Skip  |  5/2/2020  |  100
Skip  |  5/3/2020  |  100
Skip  |  5/4/2020  |  130
Skip  |  5/5/2020  |  130
Skip  |  5/6/2020  |  130
Skip  |  5/7/2020  |  130
Skip  |  5/8/2020  |  130
Skip  |  5/9/2020  |  130
Todd  |  5/1/2020  |  200
Todd  |  5/2/2020  |  200
Todd  |  5/3/2020  |  200
Todd  |  5/4/2020  |  200
Todd  |  5/5/2020  |  200
Todd  |  5/6/2020  |  200
Todd  |  5/7/2020  |  300
Todd  |  5/8/2020  |  300
Todd  |  5/9/2020  |  300
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CROSS JOIN` to generate the rows you want and `OUTER APPLY` to bring in the data that exists:

```
SELECT l.[LO], c.[CalendarDate], a.finalbp
FROM [CalendarTable] c CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT LO FROM Table1) l
     CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) a.*
      FROM [Table1] a
      WHERE a.LO = l.LO AND a.[StartDate] <= c.[CalendarDate] 
      ORDER BY a.StartDate DESC
     ) a
WHERE [CalendarDate] >= '2020-05-01' AND [CalendarDate] <= GETDATE()
```

Comment: Amazing thank you. Now I'd like to modify slightly. I'd like Todd to not have a row for 5/1/2020 because his first plan started on 5/2/2020. How can I remove rows for LOs where they haven't had their first revenue plan yet

Comment: Your sample data in the question has a row for Todd on that date.  I would suggest that you ask a NEW question with appropriate sample data, desired results and explanation.  This question has been answered.